# How to exclude few ranges from numpy array at once?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, one have a following numpy array:

```
X = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])
```

Now, how one can exclude from the array `X` ranges `X[0:2]`, `X[6:8]` and `X[12:14]` at once, so one will get in result `X= [2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]`?

Comment: How/where are those ranges stored?

Comment: I presume you mean `X[0:3],X[6:9].x[12:15]`?

Comment: One way or other you need to loop over the slices. One solution lets `np.r_` do that, another repeatedly uses `delete`, yet another combines slices.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine the ranges into a 1D array:

```
In [18]: np.r_[0:2,6:8,12:14]
Out[18]: array([ 0,  1,  6,  7, 12, 13])
```

Then use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to create a boolean array which is True at those index locations:

```
In [19]: np.in1d(np.arange(len(X)), (np.r_[0:2,6:8,12:14]))
Out[19]: 
array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False,
       False, False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

And then use[`~` to invert](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html) the boolean array:

```
In [11]: X = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])

In [12]: X[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(X)), (np.r_[0:2,6:8,12:14]))]
Out[12]: array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])
```

---

Note that `X[12:14]` captures only the first two 5's. There is one 5 left over, so the result is `array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])`, not `array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4])`.

Slice ranges in Python are half-open intervals. The left index is included, but the right index is not. So `X[12:14]` selects `X[12]` and `X[13]`, but not `X[14]`.  See [this post](https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi) for Guido van Rossum's explanation for why Python uses half-open intervals.

To get the result `[2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]` you would need to add one to the right-hand (ending) index for each slice:

```
In [17]: X[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(X)), (np.r_[0:3,6:9,12:15]))]
Out[17]: array([2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4])
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I think you could just write `np.r_[0:2, 6:8, 12:14]` instead of `np.r_[np.s_[0:2,6:8,12:14]]`.

Comment: @ajcr: Oh! Thank you for the improvement.

Comment: Or you can let `delete` construct the mask for you: `np.delete(X, np.r_[0:3,6:9,12:15])`

Comment: @hpaulj: I think that is a *much* faster method, particularly for large `X`. Would you like to write it up as a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
numbers = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
exclude = set(range(0,2) + range(6,8) + range(12,14))
[n for n in numbers if n not in exclude]
```

or:

```
[i for i in nums if i not in xrange(0,2) and i not in xrange(6,8) and i not in xrange(12,14)]
```

result:

```
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to `@unutbu`s answer I suggested `np.delete`.  Here are a few timings

A larger test array:

```
In [445]: A=np.arange(1000)
```

@unutbu's answer:

```
In [446]: timeit A[~np.in1d(np.arange(len(A)), (np.r_[10:50:3,100:200,300:350]))].shape
1000 loops, best of 3: 454 µs per loop
```

Same index list, but using `np.delete` - about 3x speedup

```
In [447]: timeit np.delete(A,np.r_[10:50:3,100:200,300:350]).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
```

But doing a straight forward boolean masking is even faster.  Earlier I deduced that `np.delete` does basically this, but it must have some added overhead (including the ability to handle multiple dimensions):

```
In [448]: %%timeit
ind=np.ones_like(A,bool)
ind[np.r_[10:50:3,100:200,300:350]]=False
A[ind].shape
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.5 µs per loop
```

`np.delete` has a different strategy when the input is a slice, which may be faster than boolean indexing.  But it only handles one slice at a time, hence the nested delete that @Kasramvd shows.  I intend to add that timing.

Concatenating multiple slices is another option.

`np.r_` also involves a loop, but it is only over the slices.  Basically it iterates over the slices, expanding each as a range, and concatenates them.  In my fastest case it is responsible for 2/3 of the run time:

```
In [451]: timeit np.r_[10:50:3,100:200,300:350]
10000 loops, best of 3: 41 µs per loop
In [453]: %%timeit x=np.r_[10:50:3,100:200,300:350]
ind=np.ones_like(A,bool)
ind[x]=False
A[ind].shape
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.2 µs per loop
```

---

The nested delete has pretty good performance:

```
In [457]: timeit np.delete( np.delete( np.delete(A,slice(300,350)),
   slice(100,200)),slice(10,50,3)).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
```

`np.delete`, when given a slice to delete, copies slices to the result array (the blocks before and after the delete block).  I can approximate that by concatenating several slices.  I'm cheating here by using delete for the 1st block, rather than take the time to write a pure copy.  Still it is faster than the best boolean mask expression.

```
In [460]: timeit np.concatenate([np.delete(A[:100],slice(10,50,3)),
   A[200:300],A[350:]]).shape
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.7 µs per loop
```

I can remove the `delete` with this slicing, though the order of the 10:50 range is messed up.  I suspect that this is, theoretically, the fastest:

```
In [480]: timeit np.concatenate([A[:10], A[11:50:3], A[12:50:3],
    A[50:100], A[200:300], A[350:]]).shape
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.1 µs per loop
```

---

An important caution - these alternatives are being tested with non-overlapping slices.  Some may work with overlaps, others might not.

Answer (score 0):

Just compose X based on the intervals you want to keep..

```
X = np.array(list(X[3:6]) + list(X[9:12]))
```

Comment: Is your `+` array addition, or list concatenation?

Comment: `X` in this question is a `numpy` array, for which `+` is addition.

Comment: Ok. I adjusted the solution

Comment: Use `np.concatenate([X[3:6], X[9:12]])` to do it entirely with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the `np.delete` 3 time and since @nneonneo said in comment do it reverse which doesn't need to calculate range offsets.  :

```
>>> np.delete(np.delete(np.delete(X,np.s_[12:14]),np.s_[6:8]),np.s_[0:2])
array([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Or you could delete ranges starting from the end, which removes the need to calculate range offsets.

Comment: `delete` when given slices (from `s_`) just copies the slices that it wants to keep to a new array.  Effectively your expression concatenates `X[2:6], X[8:12], X[14:]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is helpful but IF the output of each range is unique, you can index by range count.

```
X = numpy.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5])

A = np.unique(X)

Out[79]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Here we want to keep the second and fourth range so.

```
X = X[(X==A[1])|(X==A[3])]  

Out[82]: array([2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4])
```